# Can't figure out how to get Degres of an Analog accelerometer

Tags: arduino

I am pretty new to Arduino, And I am trying to convert voltage given from the x,y and z pins of my accelerometer.

My real problem is that I have no idea how to calculate and convert the voltage to degrees.

The way it works is pretty simple though:

Lets say when the accelerometer is flat down level I get a voltage of 2V and when it is flat on one side I get 1V. If it is flat on the other side I get 3V.  ( the numbers are for illustration only ).

Now I know that when the voltage is a 2V the accelerometer is at a degrees of 0 and if I get 2.5V it is a 45 degrees and if I get 1.5V it is -45 degrees.

Now I understand how to calculate it by very simply logic. But can't figure how on paper.

What would be the calculation to convert that?

Ps. I dont really need someone to program the whole thing for me and it is not that my question,I am simply asking how do we actually calculate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 2V => 0 degrees, 1V => -90, 3V => +90

Degrees = 90 * (V - 2);

Keep in mind that you will probably need to convert degrees to radians before using any trig functions on your value.

The answer above is based purely on the info from your question. However, I think there is probably more you will want to know about the accelerometer in the Arduino, particularly if you are wanting to do things like calculate pitch, roll, yaw.

This web site seems to have helpful info on the Arduino accelerometer: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58048.0

Comment: Thanks! that was pretty simple..  What do you mean by I should convert to radian before usings any trig function on my value ?

Comment: Most programming languages require the use of radians (instead of degrees) when using functions like sin(), cos(), tan(), etc. It is just a matter of multiplying by pi/180. Here is another web site with info: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/radians/convert-degee-to-radians.php

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the higher voltage (+90 degrees) is `b` and lower voltage is `a` (-90 degrees). So 180 degree is divided equally across the voltage range `(b-a)`. So each unit voltage is equal to `180/(b-a)` degrees. Also the voltage point `(b-a)/2` is the point where 0 degree is observed. So to calculate the degree of a supplied voltage say `x` we need to find out how far is it from the voltage point corresponding to  0 degree in terms of voltage and multiply with the number of degree per unit voltage. So the equation for the same is as follows:

```
(x-((b-a)/2))*180/(b-a)
```

You can substitute the values b = 3V, a = 1V and x =1.5/2.5V to get the values you mentioned int the question.